# Why is it correct to say "overlooks park" instead of "oversees park"?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, difference

*Choose the word or phrase that best completes each sentence.*

His bedroom ........... the park.

a) overtakes
b) undergoes
c) **overlooks** (the right answer)
d) oversees  (what I have picked)

---

When I searched the internet, I encountered a lot of examples that said **'overlooks the park.'** However, I couldn't find any that specifically used the term 'oversees.' Should I simply accept that it is what it is, or is there a specific logic behind it?

(I believe 'oversees' is typically used in the context of humans rather than places. I might be mistaken.)

*Building Skills for Proficiency, Cesur Öztürk, 57th edition*

Comment: Overlook means to be in a higher position relative to something; oversee means to supervise. Not the same meaning.

Answer (score 2):

From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/oversee):

> oversee (third-person singular simple present oversees, present participle overseeing, simple past oversaw, past participle overseen) (transitive)
>
> 1. (literally) To survey, look at something in a wide angle.
> 2. (figuratively) To supervise, guide, review or direct the actions of a person or group.
> 3. To inspect, examine
> 4. (obsolete) To fail to see; to overlook, ignore.
> 5. To observe secretly or unintentionally.

Definition 1 would work in your example, but I don't think that usage is so common. I think definitions 2 and 3 are the most common meanings of *oversee* in current usage.

On the other hand, the first verb definition of [*overlook*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/overlook) fits exactly in your sentence:

> To offer a view (of something) from a higher position.

and it fits with the only sense in which *overlook* can be used as a noun:

> A vista or point that gives a beautiful view.

Note that these exercises always ask for the *best* answer, which suggests that other choices could also be correct.